# Rest Web Services and session handling for multiple clients

Tags: c#, android, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have been working on a RESTful webservice for an android native application to consume. I choose ASP .NET WEB API. WEB API makes it very easy to create those HTTP methods in controllers, and converting our response objects into json/xml... Its simply awesome!

Now comes user authentication and those session handling parts. First I thought it will be easier to implement sessions in my RESTful service. But really frustrated with the configurations for enabling sessions in WEB API, and making the android native to handle those session ids.

1. First, Android sends login request to WEB API
2. WEB API checks authentications, and responses with a sessionid in response header
3. Now Android native reads the response header->fetches ASPNET_sessionId ->keeps in its memory
4. Further requests from android will have to set this ASPNET_sessionId in request header

*Do you think this is a proper way?*

And now I have another client. A hybrid app in Mobile jquery. Now facing following problems:

- Access-origin policy:  So I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` in response header. And it solved.
- Now I need to set session id in jquery ajax post request. And found its not possible to set headers for jquery ajax when calling a cross domain service.

*How can I manage session for my hybrid app?*

Also What are the things taken care of while creating a web service that has to be consumed from different client applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I have come with following points:

REST is stateless. So why do we need to play with session? there by giving it a stateful life?

> No need for enabling session state. When a user logins into
>   application we creates a unique id for user in database. Further
>   requests from the user will send this unique id as a part of message
>   body. Server checks this unique id every time for identifying user.

Cross-domain issue in Hybrid app

> When converting app to hybrid with cordova we found that cross domain
>   issue is not occuring. It is believed that cordova converts jquery
>   ajax requests to native requests calls from android. jsonp also found to be a good solution.

Comment: If you're creating a unique id for a user, and validating it, you are creating a state for each request.  Just because you're not using the built-in .net framework to manage state doesn't mean you're stateless. I'm not saying you're wrong to do that, it's just semantics. You are not stateless. You are mimicing the .net framework in what you're doing. It's just .net uses a cookie to validate the session, and you use a unique id in the message body.